# How to integrate a tooltip into my <div> area?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a tooltip to the entire `event1Bubble` `<div>` area in the code shown here. All the other explanations of how to add a tooltip to a `<div>` container involve adding a new `tooltip` class to it, but my `<div>` in this code already has a class, so I was hoping someone could show me how to modify the existing code to create my tooltip while preserving all the existing style information.

```css
.event1Bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.1);
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -70px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.64)
}

.event1Bubble:after,
.event1Bubble:before,
.event2Bubble:after,
.event2Bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.event1Bubble:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.66);
  border-width: 12px;
}

.event1Bubble:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Timeline">
  <div class="event1">
    <div class="event1Bubble">
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">10</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Wednesday
          <div class="MonthYear">September 2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="active">Active</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add the `.tooltip` class in addition to the existing class, does it wipe out the other styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for tooltip. then add to the div

ex:

```
.tooltip{

}
```

---

```
<div class="Timeline">
  <div class="event1">
    <div class="event1Bubble tooltip"> // like this
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">10</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Wednesday
          <div class="MonthYear">September 2018</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="active">Active</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```